# How to tell if a disk attached to an Azure Virtual Machine is encrypted?

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, encryption

I encrypted the disks of an Ubuntu 16.04 machine on Azure following [this instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-linux). Apparently the process completed successfully, however when using the command:

```
az vm encryption show --resource-group "<res-group>" --name "<vm-name>"
```

I get some confusing results:

```
{
  "disks": [
    {
      "encryptionSettings": null,
      "name": "...",
      "statuses": [
        {
          "code": "EncryptionState/notEncrypted",
          "displayStatus": "Disk is not encrypted",
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "message": "Encryption succeeded for all volumes",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "substatus": [
    {
      "code": "ComponentStatus/Microsoft.Azure.Security.AzureDiskEncryptionForLinux/succeeded",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "message": "{\"os\": \"Encrypted\", \"data\": \"NotMounted\"}",
      ....
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see I get the message *Encryption succeeded for all volumes* but at the same time *Disk is not encrypted*.

How can I tell with 100% certainty if indeed my disk is encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

For linux vms you would need to wait anywhere between 1-20 hours before disk is actually encrypted after installing the extension. And i believe you would need a reboot before it says its encrypted.

You should watch extension status, it will ask for reboot at some point in time.
Forgot to add. once you reboot it will report disks as encrypted.

For windows VMs they are "instantly" encrypted (probably after bitlocker is enabled doing encryption in the background).

Comment: If still seeing conflicting reports after reboot, please open a ticket through the portal.  I will try to reproduce on this end and open an internal ticket if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this with several of our VMs. Please check that your Azure KeyVault is enabled for disk encryption. If you look at the documentation, you'll see that it specifies that you enable the key vault for disk encryption. Missing that parameter results in the behavior you're describing.

Open up the Key Vault in the Azure Portal, select "Access Policies" from the menu on the left, and click on "Click to show advanced access policies". Make sure the "Enable access for Azure disk encryption" policy is checked.

If all is correctly set there, you should see that "Encryption is enabled on disk" in the "disks" section of the output of the "az vm encryption show" command, or in the Disks blade for the VM in Azure portal, the moment that "az vm encryption enable" returns. The encryption process itself may still take several hours, but Azure will now see the VM as encrypted.